# How to avoid OR Condition in large SQL query

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have one requirement where we need to form a dynamic SQL query which will have 100 OR conditions as shown below, The number of parameters inside the in clause can very from 1 - 50. 
All the parameters will come from UI.

No of Records in GK_QUEUE = 1,00,000 and will increase in future (200 Records per day).
No of Records in Process_type and Process_category = 60 static rows. 
No of Region code has 4 values

is there a better way to handle this instead of having this large query with or and in condition.

```
SELECT *  
FROM GK_queue UQ  
INNER JOIN PROCESS_TYPE WPT ON WPT.ID_PROCESS_TYPE = UQ.ID_PROCESS_TYPE             
INNER JOIN PROCESS_CATEGORY WPTC ON WPTC.ID_PROCESS_CATEGORY = WPT.ID_PROCESS_CATEGORY 
AND UQ.REGION_CODE IN (:regions)

OR (UQ.CURRENT_TYPE =  'G-D-CHL-TSD-PND-APPRV'  and UQ.xu in ('GH','IN'))
OR (UQ.CURRENT_TYPE =  'G-D-CHL-TSD-PND-NTFY-AMR'  and UQ.xu in (' SH7',' SHB',' SHE',' SSZ',' SZN',' TBI',' TH1',' TW1',' VNB',' VSE'))
OR (UQ.CURRENT_TYPE =  'G-D-CHL-TSD-SEND-NOTICE'  and UQ.xu in ('051',' 273',' 494',' 601',' 604',' 616',' 645',' 650',' 671'))
OR (UQ.CURRENT_TYPE =  'G-D-PRNT-G-REW-NOTFY'  and UQ.xu in (' 770',' 877',' 931',' 937',' APC',' AUS',' BJ1',' BJB',' CNY',' HK1',' ID2'))
OR (UQ.CURRENT_TYPE =  'G-D-PRNT-TSD-D-COMPLETE'  and UQ.xu in (' BJ1',' BJB',' CNY',' HK1',' ID2',' IN9',' ISE',' JPN',' KR1',' ML7',' MY1'))
OR (UQ.CURRENT_TYPE =  'G-D-PRNT-TSD-IP'  and UQ.xu in (' PH2',' PR8',' SCD',' SDL',' SG1',' SGZ',' SH7',' SHB',' SHE',' SSZ',' SZN',' TBI'))
```

Comment: Join a temp table comprising rows for each 'G-D-CHL-TSD-PND-APPRV' and 'GH','IN'

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Thanks @AlexK 

We are also exploring the option to join table. 

Only bottle neck is we have to insert around 2700 records into database on user login.

Comment: What does this query do? How does your data mode look like?

Comment: Query will fetch all the records that can be processed by user in a queue based on current_type and xu, The user authentication mechanism returns an object which has current_type and xu for the user. 

 Regarding data mode, the number of condition in in clause can vary from  1 - 50. Usually user will have 5 - 15 distinct values. And little unlikely that user have same conditions in IN clause for each current_type